# I wonder if I was right about the implement of lstm layer using keras

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, lstm

Here is my model definition:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(i, input_shape=(None, 1), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(l))

model.add(LSTM(j))
model.add(Dropout(l))

model.add(Dense(k))
model.add(Dropout(l))

model.add(Dense(1))
```

and here is result

```
p = model.predict(x_test)
plt.plot(y_test)
plt.plot(p)
```

The sequential input represents the past signal in previous time-steps, the output is predicting the signal in next time-step. After splitting the training and testing data, the predictions on the test data is as follows:

[image: 1]

The figure shows almost a perfect match with gold test data and the predictions. Is it possible to predict with such high accuracy?

I think something is wrong because there's no volatility. So I wonder if it's been implemented properly.

If the implementation is correct, how can you get the following(next) value?

Is it right to do this implement?

```
a = x_test[-1]
b = model.predict(a)
c = model.predict(b)
...
```

To sum up the question:

1. Is the implementation right way?
2. I wonder how to get the value of the next data.

```
def create_dataset(signal_data, look_back=1):
    dataX, dataY = [], []
    for i in range(len(signal_data) - look_back):
        dataX.append(signal_data[i:(i + look_back), 0])
        dataY.append(signal_data[i + look_back, 0])
    return np.array(dataX), np.array(dataY)

train_size = int(len(signal_data) * 0.80)
test_size = len(signal_data) - train_size - int(len(signal_data) * 0.05)
val_size = len(signal_data) - train_size - test_size
train = signal_data[0:train_size]
val = signal_data[train_size:train_size+val_size]
test = signal_data[train_size+val_size:len(signal_data)]

x_train, y_train = create_dataset(train, look_back)
x_val, y_val = create_dataset(val, look_back)
x_test, y_test = create_dataset(test, look_back)
```

I use `create_dataset` with `look_back=20`.

`signal_data` is preprocessed with min-max normalisation `MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))`.

Comment: could you provide an example of your data? if this is correct `model.predict(x_test)` then this is incorrect `model.predict(x_test[-1])`.

Comment: what do you mean by "the value of the next data"?

Comment: I have test data and using test dataset, I want to predict next day close value

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Q6Lh07Yg-OGtuz_Rvy979gcA65jrEqVNJNjndklCbg4/edit?usp=sharing here is my dataset and I use only close data

Comment: The model is not predicting a sequence. It only predicts one number. Oddly, your plot doesn't match any of the values. it seems you are plotting values between [0,1] but your sample data is not like this...

Comment: Because I preprocessed it. `scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))`

Comment: the reason I ask for the data is to understand the question. It is definitely possible to get such accuracy if the degree of freedom is limited in feature space.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197430/discussion-between-mehdi-and-gobackess).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the implementation right way?

Your code seems correct. I think you are not getting surprising results. You need to compare the results with a baseline that next prediction is randomly sampled from the range of possible day-to-day change. This way at least you can understand if your model is doing better than random sampling.

```
delta_train = train[1][1:] - train[1][:-1]
delta_range_train = delta_train.max()-delta_train.min()

# generating the baseline based on the change range in training:
random_p = test[0][:, -1] + (np.random.rand(test[0].shape[0])-0.5)*delta_range_train
```

You can check if your results are better than just a random sample `random_p`.

> I wonder how to get the value of the next data.

this gives you the last data point in the test set:

```
a = x_test[-1:]
```

then, here you are predicting the next point day:

```
b = model.predict(a)
```

based on `look_back` you may need to keep some of the datapoints from to predict the next-next point:

```
c = model.predict(np.array([list(a[0,1:])+[b]])
```

Comment: I have a question so, if you can please help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57422128/how-can-you-get-the-followingnext-value-of-stock-pricetime-series